# How to callback to a userform method in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to allow Bloomberg to populate data during a recalculation.  The Bloomberg API help says the correct way to do this is via an Application.OnTime callback.

Is there a way to callback to a sub on the form?  All of the following pseudo code is in the same project (an add-in if it matters).

Thanks for taking the time to think about my question!

Userform1

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
  glcsBBerg.refreshBB "userform1.nextStep"
end sub

public sub nextStep()
  'Continue business logic here
end sub
```

Class gclsBBerg

```
public sub refreshBB(aNextProcess as String)
  'test to see if BB has refreshed
  if refreshComplete then
    Application.Run aNextProcess '**VBA can't find userform1.nextStep **
  else 
    Application.OnTime (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)), "CheckIfDone"
  end if
```

Comment: is there a specific reason that forces you to keep the sub as a public method of the form rather than as a normal procedure into a module ? Moreover, you say `gclsBBerg` is a class... could you show us where you instantiate the class for us to understand better the structure of the code?

Comment: LOL ... The programming answer is encapsulation, all the logic in a single place.  The practical answer is inertia ... I already have the logic for nextStep() written on the form and it relies on various form objects (listboxes, captions and text boxes)  to do its job.  If there is no way to callback to the form, I will restructure into modules but wanted to check before I change as it affects multiple forms.

Comment: Ok, we can still give a try: can you modify the class gclsBBerg? If yes, I could try to sketch an answer but I cannot really test it, so I will eventually remove it if it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Yes, I can modify any / all of the modules, forms and classes.

Comment: It seems like you might be confusing instance names and Class names. UserForm1 is the name of the class of form. You need to declare a variable - e.g. `Dim UF1 as Userform1: Set UF1 = New UserForm1: UF1.Name = "UF1": UF1.Show` you also need to add the Name property to the UserForm1 class. Then pass Me.Name + ".nextstep" to refreshBB

Answer (score 0):

This is a *possible* way of doing what you want, but please don't hesitate to inform me if it doesn't work so I will remove the answer: unfortunately there's no way for me to test it (I should have your project and your BB API).

### Class gclsBBerg

```
public sub refreshBB(uf As UserForm1) '<--pass the userform into the macro by reference
  'test to see if BB has refreshed
  if refreshComplete then
    uf.nextStep '<-- the method is public so the instance should be able to call it from outside
  else 
    Application.OnTime (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)), "CheckIfDone"
  end if
```

### Userform1

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
  glcsBBerg.refreshBB Me '<-- pass the form into the method of the class
end sub

public sub nextStep()
  'Continue business logic here
end sub
```

Please note: in *theory*, this works. It is possible to pass by reference an instance of the UserForm into an external routine and still allow it to interact with it. In *practice*, we're still talking about an API so I don't know at what extent they don't have restrictions on stuffs like this.

Comment: Matteo NNZ thanks for the complete answer with code examples!!  
This works for the simple case I outlined but gets "ugly" when working with multiple forms.  To make refreshBB work with multiple forms, I have to pass in an Object and then a series of TypeOf checks to see which form was passed in.  It gets worse when I need to refresh BBerg from the same form multiple times as I need a second argument to determine which method to call back.

Comment: @timothyvogel well clearly your code needs some refactoring to work properly in the real case, but I think this is the way you should go for (passing the string and trying to run a method of an object without the object really exists is impossible, you might want anyway to play with existing instances).